# import of mail folders by Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

My company is no longer supporting our Linux mail server (all will be handled by gmail).

Over the years I've run many mail clients on the Linux server: elm, alpine, squirrelMail, roundCube. My most recent client has been RoundCube.

Ideally I'd like Thunderbird to import the most current folders from RoundCube; these appear to me to be inside Maildir/ (with deeper directories like .saved-mailed, etc). But I also have Mail/ (which alpine appears to reference).

But upon adding this account to Thunderbird, some mix of folders is presented to me: not all from Maildir/ and not all from Mail/...in fact no 'new' Roundcube folders are presented.

Where does Thunderbird search on a linux mail server to 'subscribe' folders? And how can I access this location to force the subscription of the folders I actually want?

Answer (score 0):

I gave up trying to determine where Thunderbird (Tb) searches for mail.
Instead I copied all Roundcube email in Maildir/ to my local machine and then used the code here
https://gist.github.com/lftbrts/249f034a439d3eb2e008f73506cacc2d
to convert that email to mbox format.

Then I copied all that converted email to Tb's 'Local Folders' directory; Tb was able to load all the converted folders and then I 'dragged' them (using Tb) to the synced Gmail account.
So the above named coded saved the day!